# how to draw a graph in R by considering edges length

Tags: r, graph

I use  igraph in R for drawing a network graph in R,but I cant get a graph based on the edges length (eg (A,B) 5cm , (B,C) 2cm).please help me to sole the problem. How can I assign the particular distance in this program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layout to plot the vertex at certain position. You can define the layout in a manner that respect a certain distance between vertex.
A layout is defined in a matrix with 2 columns and a row for each node.  The first column indicates its x position and the second its y position.

Here an example:

```
library(igraph)
gg <- graph.ring(4)
ll =matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,3,0,5),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
plot(gg,layout=ll)
```

[image]